# Shared memory pages and fork

Tags: linux, kernel

If the parent is sharing some pages with another process and we fork the parent. From what I know the child copies the page tables and we set the pages as read-only and do Copy-On-Write. But this will create a copy of the shared memory page if we write to it which is wrong. How does the Linux kernel avoid this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kernel knows which memory pages were allocated using shared memory operations. When a child is forked, those pages are not marked Copy-on-Write, so they will remain shared among all the processes.

This is recorded in the `vm_area_struct` data structure, in the `vm_flags` member. One of the flags is `VM_SHARED`. mm/memory.c contains the following function that determines if a page should be converted to COW

```
static inline int is_cow_mapping(vm_flags_t flags)
{
        return (flags & (VM_SHARED | VM_MAYWRITE)) == VM_MAYWRITE;
}
```

If you want to see more about how this flag is set and used, go to [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.linux.no/) and search for VM_SHARED.

Comment: When can I read about the data structures used by the kernel to store this? What other pages are not marked read-only?